# update the boolean field with hard condition - django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It's a little difficult. if some user like some post and then call the function **allPost** (in views.py) it should return `is_liked=True` in `serializer.data`.

like this:

```
{
        "id": 48,
        "body": "like me",
        "date": "2020-12-15T11:39:58.233912+06:00",
        "user": {}//objects
        "total_likes": 4,
        "liked_by": {}//object
        "total_comments": 0,
        "is_liked":true
    },
  {
        "id": 47,
        "body": "hello",
        "date": "2020-12-15T10:53:56.047665+06:00",
        "user": {},//object
        "total_likes": 2,
        "liked_by": [
            {
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": ""
            },
            {
                "first_name": "test3",
                "last_name": "three"
            }
        ],
        "total_comments": 0,
        "is_liked": false
    },
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='liked_by')
    is_liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializers()
    total_likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    liked_by = SimpleUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    total_comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','body','date','user','total_likes','liked_by','total_comments','is_liked')

    def get_total_likes(self, instance):
        return instance.liked_by.count()

    def get_total_comments(self, instance):
        return instance.comment_set.count()
```

urls.py:

```
path('myapi/likepost/<str:pk>/', views.likePost, name='likePost'),
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def allPost(request):
    user = request.user.id
    allpost = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializer(allpost, many=True)
    liked = Post.objects.filter(liked_by__id=user).values_list('id', flat=True)

#--> i think, code should be written here

    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def likePost(request, pk):
    user = request.user.id
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    previous_user = post.liked_by.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
    liked_by = [user]
    for i in previous_user:
        liked_by.append(i)
    data = {'liked_by':liked_by}
    serializer = CreatePostSerializer(instance=post, data=data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)

    return Response({'response': 'ok'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_total_likes(self, instance):
        a= instance.liked_by.count()
        if(a>0):
            instance.is_liked=True
            instance.save()
        return instance.liked_by.count()
```

Did you mean something like this?